# PHP: Signed Binary Strings

Tags: php, flash, bit

I'm having a problem with converting binary strings to signed integers

If you call decbin('-40'), php will output 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011000

But if you call bindec(decbin('-40')), it will output 1.84467440737E+19 (or something similar, which is obviously not -40) because it "sees the most significant bit as another order of magnitude rather than as the sign bit" - php manual

Is there a way to convert a binary 64 bit binary string (much like the one output by decbin) string into a signed integer?

Comment: Try the base_convert function.

Comment: see this comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.bindec.php#79072

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, you cannot use `bindec`

> bindec() interprets all binary_string values as unsigned integers. This is because bindec() sees the most significant bit as another order of magnitude rather than as the sign bit.

`base_convert` appears to ignore signing altogether.

If you know that your incoming string **will always** be 64 bit binary and you are **not** on a 32 bit system, it's quite easy to write a custom function.

- Check if the string is 64 characters long.
- Check if the most significant bit is a 1.
- Flip all bits
- Add 1
- Negate

Here's a quick one I knocked together.

```
function bindec2($bin)
{
    if (strlen($bin) == 64 && $bin[0] == '1') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 64; $i++) {
            $bin[$i] = $bin[$i] == '1' ? '0' : '1';
        }

        return (bindec($bin) + 1) * -1;
    }
    return bindec($bin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm! The data I have is actually minimized to save space, and I pad the extra 1's or 0's to actually make it 64 bits long - and the system is a 64 bit system so I don't think I will run to any problems by removing the length check.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) to convert between int and binary string.

```
// 'i' means signed integer
var_dump(unpack('i', pack('i', '-40'))); // gives you -40
```

Comment: I don't have the luxury of using -40 my friend, the data I have is in the format output of bindec